# Extract certain values from a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
filter-sex=1,1_filter-size=2,3_filter-material=3,5
```

How can I extract only the numeric pairs from it ("1,1", "2,3" and "3,5") and put them in an array?

I know I can use explode() multiple times, but I was wondering if there's an easy way using regex.

I'm using PHP.

Comment: i know this is tagged "regex" but what about using explode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This :

```
preg_match_all('/(?<==)\d+,\d+/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

should get all your number in the $result array.

**Why:**

```
"
(?<=    # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   =       # Match the character “=” literally
)
\d      # Match a single digit 0..9
   +       # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
,       # Match the character “,” literally
\d      # Match a single digit 0..9
   +       # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"
```

Comment: Thanks! It's ok but without the second line.

Comment: @Psyche Yeah, that's just an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Well this `/\d,\d/` should match all the single-digit number pairs, use it with with [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get an array of strings `num,num`. If you expect multi-digit numbers, use `/\d+,\d+/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

http://codepad.org/jtWs6DjM

But it returns also the strings before:

```
<?php
$string = "filter-sex=1,1_filter-size=2,3_filter-material=3,5";

$result = preg_split('/[a-z-_]+=([0-9],[0-9])/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($result);

?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,1
    [1] => 2,3
    [2] => 3,5
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want only the numeric pairs.

Comment: Updated so it only returns numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "filter-sex=1,1_filter-size=2,3_filter-material=3,5";

preg_match_all("#[0-9]+,[0-9]+#", $str, $res);    
print_r($res);

?>
```